# Why isn't the image appearing on my Flask app with YOLOV5 model after clicking upload?

Tags: html, flask, yolov5

I'm trying to build an app that can detect cavities in oral images using the YOLOV5 algorithm. I have an error when the user clicks upload it doesn't show the image in the browser, however, I can see the image saved in my app.

I tried tO print the image url and i get  "Image URL: /static//static/1685369990.0033317.jpg", Which is a wrong path the image should be in static/img.jpg

This is my app.py code:

```
import io
import os
import time
import torch
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw, ImageFont
from flask import Flask, jsonify, url_for, render_template, request, redirect

app = Flask(__name__, static_url_path='/static')

RESULT_FOLDER = os.path.join('static')
app.config['RESULT_FOLDER'] = RESULT_FOLDER

model = torch.hub.load('ultralytics/yolov5', 'custom', path='./best.pt')
model.eval()


def draw_boxes(image, boxes, labels):
    draw = ImageDraw.Draw(image)
    font = ImageFont.truetype("arial.ttf", size=12)
    
    for box, label in zip(boxes, labels):
        x1, y1, x2, y2, _, cls = box.tolist()
        draw.rectangle([x1, y1, x2, y2], outline='red', width=2)
        
        text = f'{label}: {int(cls)}'
        text_width, text_height = font.getsize(text)
        draw.rectangle([x1, y1 - text_height, x1 + text_width, y1], fill='red')
        draw.text((x1, y1 - text_height), text, fill='white', font=font)
        
    return image


def get_prediction(img_bytes):
    img = Image.open(io.BytesIO(img_bytes))
    imgs = [img]  # batched list of images

    # Inference
    results = model(imgs, size=640)  # includes NMS
    boxes = results.xyxy[0]  # Get bounding boxes
    labels = results.names[0]  # Get class labels
    
    # Draw bounding boxes and labels on the original image
    img_with_boxes = draw_boxes(img, boxes, labels)

    return img_with_boxes, boxes


@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def predict():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if 'file' not in request.files:
            return redirect(request.url)
        file = request.files.get('file')
        if not file:
            return

        img_bytes = file.read()

        try:
            img_with_boxes, boxes = get_prediction(img_bytes)

            img_name = str(time.time()) + '.jpg'
            img_path = os.path.join(app.config['RESULT_FOLDER'], img_name)

            img_with_boxes.save(img_path)
            
            #image_url = '/' + img_path

            image_url = url_for('static', filename=img_name)
            print("Image URL:", image_url)

            return render_template('test.html', result_image= image_url)


        except Exception as e:
            print(str(e))  # Print the exception for debugging
            return render_template('error.html', error=str(e))

    return render_template('index.html')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```